# Removing tab delimited spaces from a text file using for loop

Tags: python, loops, split, strip

For my python class, I am working on opening a .tsv file and taking 15 rows of data, broken down in 4 columns, and turning it into lists for each line.  To do this, I must remove the tabs in between each column.

I've been advised to use a for loop and loop through each line.  This makes sense but I can't figure out how to remove the tabs.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

To read lines from a file, and split each line on the tab delimiter, you can do this:

```
rows = []
for line in open('file.tsv', 'rb'):
    rows.append(line.strip().split('\t'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Properly, this should be done using the [Python CSV module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) (as mentioned in another answer) as this will handle escaped separators, quoted values etc.

In the more general sense, this can be done with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
rows = [line.split('\t') for line in file]
```

And, as suggested in the comments, in some cases a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) would be a better choice:

```
rows = (line.split('\t') for line in file)
```

See [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) for some discussion on when to use each.

Comment: I would actually use a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) here instead of a list comprehension, so that you're not holding a bunch of lists in memory while you process them. Depends on what you're doing with the results, though.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Python's stdlib csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), particularly the [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) function.

```
rows = [row for row in csv.reader(open('yourfile.tsv', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')]
```

There's also a a `dialect` parameter that can take [excel-tab](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.excel_tab) to conform to Microsoft Excel's tab-delimited format.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [built-in string functions](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html). `split()` should do the job.

```
>>> line = 'word1\tword2\tword3'
>>> line.split('\t')
['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```